# extract hashtag with emoji in python

Tags: python, emoji, hashtag

I want to extract all hashtags from text even those hashtag contains unicode or emoji. If the hashtag has space with emoji, I will not include it because we have space between hashtag and emoji. For example, I have test string as below.

```
test = 'abc #yes blabla #No blabla #nah '
```

Here's my current code I made which shows:

```
re.findall(r'\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*' , test)

['#yes', '#No', '#nah']
```

However, my target answer is:

```
['#yes', '#No', '#nah']
```

Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is \w is equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_] .  Use \S (not-whitespace) instead.

```
import re

test = 'abc #yes blabla #No blabla #nah '
res = re.findall(r'\B#\S+' , test)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['#yes', '#No', '#nah']
```

Comment: Thank you. This completely solve this issue.